# Converting stateful to stateless component

Tags: reactjs

I have this working stateful component in React:

```
import React, {Component}  from "react";

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
            array: [],
            noresults: false
        };
  }
  
  loadData = () => {
    let data = this.myRef.current.value;
    let url = "someurl="+data;
    if(!data) {
      return;
    }
        fetch(url)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                if(json.data.length > 0) {
                  this.setState({
                      array: json.data,
                      noresults: false
                  });
                } else {
                  this.setState({
                      noresults: true
                  });
                }
                
            })
    }
render() {
  const { array, noresults } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <input ref={this.myRef} type="number"/>
        <button onClick={this.loadData}>Click Here</button>
      </section>

    
    <ul>
        
        {
                array.map((e) => ( 
                <li key = { e.key } >
                    { e.data }
                    </li>
                ))
            }
      </ul>

      {noresults && <div>No Records</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default MyComponent
```

I want to convert this to stateless like this:

```
function MyComponent() {

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <input type="number"/>
        <button>Click Here</button>
      </section>

      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>

      <div>No Records</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent
```

Now how can I pass data of input to my method to make API call. Also how to pass the response from API to display as ul and li elements?

Comment: The answer is that you should not do this in React. React would much prefer you do this with state and controlled inputs, not state-less uncontrolled inputs. To accomplish what you would like to accomplish takes away a lot of the value of the declarative programming React offers. But if you want to do it, just do it exactly like you would in vanilla javascript, when the button is clicked call a function that grabs the elements from the page, or use refs to accomplish the same goal, grab the value property of the input, and hand it to your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it as component props:

```
const MyComponent = ({array = [], loadData = () => {}}) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();
  
  const handleInputChange = (evt) => {
    setInputValue(evt.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <input type="number" onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <button onClick={e => loadData(e, inputValue)}>Click Here</button>
      </section>

      <ul>
          {array.map((e) => (<li key={e.key}>{e.data}</li>))}
      </ul>

      {array.length === 0 && <div>No Records</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

For input, I created a local state which is updated on input change and passed it to `loadData` function. You can access the current value by parametrizing `loadData` function:

```
loadData = (e, currentInputValue) => { ... };
```

Comment: I think you may have missed the part of his post where he said wants to pass the current value of his input to his API when that button is clicked.

Comment: How to pass value of `<input type="number"/>` to loadData method?

Comment: @learner Updated